# fwrite() Isn't creating nor writing to a file that I specify it to

Tags: php, file-io, fopen, fwrite

"LoggedIn" does = true and "CurrentUser" isn't "ManselD", yet it's still not writing or creating the file :(
And yes my /accounts/logs folder is CHMOD 702

```
if(!$user == "ManselD"){
    ini_set('date.timezone', 'Europe/London');
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $txt = "$user Logged In With The Ip: $ip At ".date("h:i")."\n";
    $url = "/accounts/logs/".trim(date('F')."-".date('d')."-".date('Y').".txt");
    $file = fopen($url, "a");
    fwrite($file, $txt);
    fclose($file);
    echo $file;
    if(is_writable("/accounts/logs")){
        echo "It is writable";
    } else{
        echo "It isn't writable";
    }
}
```

I'm literally stumped and baffled at why this doesn't work :S

FIXED VERSION:

```
if($user != "ManselD"){
ini_set('date.timezone', 'Europe/London');
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$txt = "$user Logged In With The Ip: $ip At ".date("h:i")."\n";
$url = getcwd() . '/accounts/logs/'.trim(date('F')."-".date('d')."-".date('Y').".txt");
file_put_contents($url, $txt, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Comment: Testing the value of $file after the fopen() would be a start; test the /accounts/logs directory for is_writeable() via code; do you have display_errors enabled?

Comment: I would also look in the error log files to see if there's an error

Comment: `!$_SESSION['CurrentUser'] == "ManselD"` doesn't do what you think it does.  That's equivalent to `(!$_SESSION['CurrentUser']) == "ManselD"`, you most likely want `$_SESSION['CurrentUser'] != "ManselD"`.

Comment: Ok, i put this:
if(!$user == "ManselD"){
ini_set('date.timezone', 'Europe/London');
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$txt = "$user Logged In With The Ip: $ip At ".date("h:i")."\n";
$url = "/accounts/logs/".trim(date('F')."-".date('d')."-".date('Y').".txt");
$file = fopen($url, "a");
fwrite($file, $txt);
fclose($file);
echo $file;
if(is_writable("/accounts/logs")){
echo "It is writable";
}else{
echo "It isn't writable";
}
}
and it outputs nothing, i added "ini_set('display_errors', '1');"
Up the top of the script D:

Comment: Please edit your original post if you want to add code...

Comment: @ManselD: Again `if(!$user == "ManselD")` is wrong!  That's like doing `((!$user) == "ManselD")`, which will convert `$user` to a boolean (and invert it).  Use `($user != "ManselD")`

Comment: Thank you rocket, So I've been doing that wrong for ages...
Well thank you so much! you've fixed my problem :)

Comment: Glad I could help! :-D

Comment: so, just for clarity's sake, was the problem the incorrect usage of the `!=` , or the incorrect path? Or both?

Comment: @Cashew: Sounds like it was both.

Comment: It was actually only the !=
But I changed the path to rocket's way. :p

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem (that you are asking about, because there are more if you read the comments) is that you write

```
$url = "/accounts/logs/".trim(date('F')."-".date('d')."-".date('Y').".txt");
```

The file paths are not URLs. And while the above is obviously not a URL, it should probably not have the starting slash (/).
A good approach would be to always use absolute paths, possibly using the `__FILE__` constant.

Comment: I second this. I personally use getcwd() to get the current working directory path then I add whatever the path is from there. For example: `$url = getcwd() . '/myFolder/' . $whateverFileName`

Comment: Thanks. I generally avoid that function, because I write code for Joomla, and my extensions get installed on environments where you NEVER know what the last extension called before your own, did to the current working directory, and you can never really be sure of what that is. :)

Comment: Hrm, ok well now it says that it isn't writable...
I set the CHMOD correctly. It should be working :/

Comment: @mavrosxristoforos what? lol I have no idea what you're talking about. Glad I'm not involved in any Joomla, then. :P jk I think I know what you mean